# SOAP request with username and password authentication in SoapUI

Tags: soap, soapui, ws-security

I am trying to make a SOAP request in SoapUI, which needs authentication with username and password. I let SoapUI generate a test based on a wsdl file and try to call the service. I followed the steps on the SoapUI website to use authentication(https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html), but I can't get it to work. I am new to SOAP, so I'm probably missing something basic. I got a username and a password for the service, so I'm guessing this is a basic authentication. But when I try to make a request, I always get a PolicyViolationException, which states that "Required policies have not been provided: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/opencsa/sca/200912}clientAuthentication".

Here is, how the request and answer look like (I obscured the service link and changed the username). I also added the user into my project and WS-Security settings.

[image: SoapUI request and response]

[image: Project setting]

I tried Pre-emptive authentication and "Must Understand". I also tried to change the request Header and add the security manually, but nothing seems to work and I always get the same response.

[image: Edited Header manually]

Comment: Either in wsdl or in documentation the service provider must have provided the information, what type of authentication mechanism is required to call the given service.

Comment: In the wsdl I can only find definitions for the body and in the documentation there it says that the header needs a UsernameToken with Username and Password fields. There are also example queries, which looks like on my last picture.

Comment: OK, then most probably they need WSSecurity only.

Comment: And that means what? As I said I am new to SOAP and SoapUI. So how should I be able to send a request? Which settings do I need or should I be able to send a request without any settings and just manually changing the rewuest with username and password?

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment yet so I'm writing as answer. To me it seems like some namespaces missing. Try to make request as follows by changing nonce, created fields. sample-token can be anything you want. If the service that you're trying to call wants password as plain text then namespace in the code sample will be enough. Also I suggest you to check documentation in this [link](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm).

```
<soap:Header>
    <Security
        xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="sample-token"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce>some-base64</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
</soap:Header>
```